# Rails - where to store collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

I have many `select` options in my forms with a collection of possible options.

E.g.:

```
title_options = %w[Mr Mrs Miss Ms Dr]
```

In my view, I will render the `select` (using formtastic):

```
<%= f.input :title, :as => :select, :collection => title_options %>
```

Currently, though, I store the title options in a `helper` file with many methods for each `select`:

```
module SelectHelper
  def days_options
    ...
  end

  def title_options
    ...
  end

  ..
end
```

Then, in a model for validation I can either extend this helper:

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend SelectHelper 
  validates :title, :inclusion => {:in => title_options}
end
```

or duplicate the options:

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :inclusion => {:in = %w[Mr Mrs Miss Ms Dr]}
end
```

Is there a better way to store the collection, for example, as a method in the model directly? I don't see it necessary to store these options in a database as they shouldn't ever change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to simplify things, you can store this collections in a constant inside your class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  TITLES = %w[Mr Mrs Miss Ms Dr]
  validates :title, :inclusion => {:in => TITLES}
```

Comment: There's a small typo. It should be `{:in => TITLES}` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [enumerated_attribute gem](https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) or some of same functionality